# i cant show menu correctly in php? please advice

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I want to show menu like this

[image: the incorrect menu]

This menu shoul look like 
[image: correct menu]

and should be dynamic. This means if we add new categories or subcategories so design should be same.

// HERE IS MY CODE , I AM USING PHP

```
      <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">

        <li class="col-sm-4">
          <ul>
            <?php
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '0' ");
            while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
            echo '<li class="dropdown-header">'.$res['cat_name'].'</li>';
            $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '".$res['cat_Id']."' ");
            while($res1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
            {
            echo '<li><a href="products.php?subCatId='.$res1['cat_Id'].'">'.$res1['cat_name'].'</a></li>';
            }

            }
            ?>

          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
```

Comment: you should read these.. [why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1) && [how can I prevent sql injection in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Are you use bootstrap? You want to display 3 column menu?

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap , please see the links on the question it has two menu images of incorrected and corrected menu

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpYl9.png     i want to show like this menu and using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Your menu function :

```
function getMenuTree($parent_id) 
{
    global $con;
    $menu = "";
    $sqlquery = " SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '$parent_id'";
    $res=mysql_query($con,$sqlquery);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
    {
           $menu .="<li><a href='products.php?subCatId='.$row['cat_Id'].''>".$row['cat_name']."</a>";

           $menu .= "<ul>".getMenuTree($row['cat_Id'])."</ul>";

           $menu .= "</li>";

    }

    return $menu;
}
```

You can call the function where you want:

```
getMenuTree('0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. I think it will work for you.

I have added `<div class="col-sm-4">` after the first while loop start, and close `</div>` before the first while loop end. this class divide categories in 3 part.

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
        <li class="col-sm-4">
          <ul>          
            <?php
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '0' ");
                while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                    // add below line
                    echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';

                    echo '<li class="dropdown-header">'.$res['cat_name'].'</li>';
                    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '".$res['cat_Id']."' ");

                    while($res1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
                    {
                        echo '<li><a href="products.php?subCatId='.$res1['cat_Id'].'">'.$res1['cat_name'].'</a></li>';
                    }

                    // add below line
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```